# Verify WS-security password digest in PHP SOAP SERVER

Tags: php, soap, ws-security, soapserver

I need to implement WS-Security password digest on PHP-Soap webservice. I looked everywhere on how to do it and I've found nothing. through trial and error I've found out that PHP Soap server will call a "Secutity" function implemented in Service class where verification will be performed.
For now my function looks like this:

```
public function Security($UsernameToken)
{

    $this->log($UsernameToken);
    $loggHelper = [];
    $loggHelper['nonce'] = unpack('H*', base64_decode($UsernameToken->Nonce))[1];
    $loggHelper['created'] = pack('a*', $UsernameToken->Created);
    $loggHelper['password'] = pack('a*', 'test');
    $loggHelper['passhash1'] = base64_encode(pack('H*',sha1($loggHelper['nonce'].$UsernameToken->Created.$loggHelper['password'])));
    $this->log($loggHelper);
    if($UsernameToken->Password==$loggHelper['passhash1'])
        return true;
    else
    {
        return new SoapFault("401", "Prohibited");
    }

}
```

The problem is, that my Digest is not the same as the password provided by test client (SoapUI)

Log output looks like this:

```
$UsernameToken = {"Username":"test","Password":"HMxOK\/pg3mOq71N2F5Znb7xDdcw=","Nonce":"BgbT8vrQb\/afX7OC3KPb0Q==","Created":"2020-06-24T07:31:11.731Z"}

$loggerHelper = {"nonce":"0606d3f2fad06ff69f5fb382dca3dbd1","created":"2020-06-24T07:31:11.731Z","password":"test","passhash1":"gJGXpD3yYDmLY6qMhRtKYWr33IA="}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some remarks:

- For security reasons you should NOT log any credentials - everybody able to access the log files has access to credentials!
- SHA1 is NOT a secure encryption algorithm at all - see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48289/how-secure-is-sha1-what-are-the-chances-of-a-real-exploit

I would suggest to use

- https://www.php.net/openssl_encrypt
- https://www.php.net/openssl_decrypt

for encryption, which is contained in PHP itself.

Or you use a framework which handles security under the hood. As an example (but I am not sure) symfony should do this automatically for you - please read more at https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/soap_web_service.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it pointed me into the right direction. Just to clarify, I logged this things only for debug purposes, SHA1  is a required algorithm in WS-Security standard so you have to use it regardless of how week it is. For the people who will search for this in the future, here's the link to the page that helped me: [link[(https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html). Once again, thanks for the answer and Your time.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved your problem. If this answer was the solution/reason please mark it as the `accepted answer`.